# Passing hexadecimal hash value to JDBC query

Tags: sql, jdbc, hex, md5, resultset

I have  a table in my MYSQL database with hexadecimal(md5 hash values), I pick the values in one Query1 iterate over the resultset RS1 and Now I need to Fetch data from another table which has this hash value in the key column..I get an sql syntax error for executing the same:

```
String targetQuery = "select hashValue from targettbl ";
        String sourceQuery = "select st.* from sourcetbl st where seqNo in" +
                "(select seqNo from sourcetblkey where hashValue in (?)" ; 
        try {
            stmt1 = conn.createStatement();
            stmt2 = conn.prepareStatement(sourceMD5Query);
            rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery(targetMd5Query);

            while(rs1.next())
            {
                stmt2.setString(1, rs1.getString(1));
                rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery(sourceQuery);
                ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs2.getMetaData();
                int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();
                while(rs2.next())
                {
                    System.out.println("Source Row");
                    for(int i=1;i<columnsNumber;i++)
                        {
                        System.out.println(""+rs2.getString(i));
                        }
                }
            }
```

Error:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Pls help

Answer (score 0):

There is a `)`missing at end of your statement. Change it to this:

```
String sourceQuery = "select st.* from sourcetbl st where seqNo in" +
                "(select seqNo from sourcetblkey where hashValue in (?))" ;
```

Comment: Apart from this problem, you can't execute a `PreparedStatement` using one of the execute methods that take a query string (those are only for a normal `Statement`). The OP needs to use `executeQuery()` (no parameters)

Comment: ) was a typo,corrected it.thanks Same for executeQuery() method..but coming back to the question: how shall I pass a hash hex value in my query

Comment: @user2176576 it is a string so you can use it as it is.

Comment: Not getting the SQLException now..but I am not getting the result..the Hash value is an MD5 hash value fetched from the database in the first (outer) query

Comment: @user2176576 Why you use `IN`? if it is only one value you can use the equals sign. Can you check if the value is the expected value and run the query in d db browser?

Comment: tried with = , still not working..no result fetched, any other way to pass a hash hex value in jdbc query?